# Which events give stacks of resumes?

Tags: recruitment, hiring, recruiting

just new to the recruiting job (tech industry in silicon valley). I'm tasked to find quality new grads, masters students etc for software engineering.

What are the different places (preferably free) where I can get stacks of resumes? Can I go to universities and ask for resumes? how does all of that work?

We are low of $ so cant spend money to get resumes but want to be resourceful. Really appreciate all the help as I am the sole recruiter (though it's not my main task here, I do devops for the startup as well). We will hopefully get a full time recruiter soon...but until then, I could really use your help!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the responses everyone (yes i know im a noob). One more question: With job applications, when they apply, will i just get a bunch of resumes as pdfs? Also for conferences, etc, are the resume batches I get a zipfile of pdfs or something?

Comment: Normally people use... job applications to get stacks of resumes?

Comment: Going through a stack of resumes is not free. You are much better of paying for resumes qualified to the job at hand.  Posting a job is cheap.  Job post is way cheaper than than a quality masters students in software engineering.   Makes no sense to cheap the selection process.

Comment: Many universities that have internship/co-op requirements will have a department that assists students in finding placements.  If you are looking for entry level resumes it may be worthwhile to begin discussions there with the expectation that these will be available after their expected graduation date.

Comment: I would recommend you forget lists of resume's but rather look into Google Xray and Boolean search strings. Sourcing is the dark art of recruitment, only understood through hands on experience. However, experience is a hard master as she gives the lesson after the test. T

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone (yes i know im a noob). One more question: With job applications, when they apply, will i just get a bunch of resumes as pdfs? Also for conferences, etc, are the resume batches I get a zipfile of pdfs or something?

Answer (score 6):

Print out your job advertisement a few times.

Put tear-off strips at the bottom with your contact details.

Pin the flyer to lamp-posts surrounding your university of choice.

Result: Free resumes.

Comment: If you can work the phrase "free beer" into the job advert you'll double the number of CVS easily.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone (yes i know im a noob). One more question: With job applications, when they apply, will i just get a bunch of resumes as pdfs? Also for conferences, etc, are the resume batches I get a zipfile of pdfs or something?

Answer (score 2):

Two common options for this are either career fairs or actually posting a job.

Talk to local universities as you may also be able to post your jobs online through systems they have.

You can also see if you can give presentations at campuses, we have a lot of university outreach and get a lot of publicity that way.

Ultimately there's not an easy button for "get list of qualified candidates for free."

Comment: With job applications, when they apply, will i just get a bunch of resumes as pdfs? Also for conferences, etc, are the resume batches I get a zipfile of pdfs or something?